# How to get the clicked menu details

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

i have jquery menu like

```
<ul id="fileMenu">
    <li>Refresh</li>
    <li>-</li>
    <li>Exit</li>
</ul>
<ul  id="editMenu">
    <li>Add</li>
    <li>Edit</li>
    <li>Delete</li>
</ul>
```

i got the way to get click event on child menu items like

```
  $('#fileMenu').on('click', 'li', function () {
            alert("Hello"); // Or make($(this)); if you still want that extra function
        });
```

But, how to find out the particular menu option, i.e user clicked on Open, Exit, Edit, delete etc...

Comment: $(this) gets clicked element, what do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use clicked element context `this` to create jquery selector along with `.text()` to get the text in it.

You will also need to add other parent ul selector(like `#editMenu`) to target their elements as well
:

```
$('#fileMenu,#editMenu').on('click', 'li', function () {
        var currenttext=$(this).text();
        alert(currenttext); 
        if(currenttext=="Add"){
            //perform Add
        }else if(currenttext=="Delete"){
            //perform delete
        }else{
            //perform edit 
        }    
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, for help.  what is the best way to compare in jquery i.e how we use switch in c++ or c#, what is the best way to compare and perform things?

Comment: what do you want to use in switch condition?

Comment: if i have 3 menus like, add, delete & edit. all will hit same function. here i have to compare i.e $(this).text() == Add, $(this).text()==delete. i just asked the best way to comapre?

Comment: you can use if,else-if,else in this case

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjLwesjq/1/)

```js
 $('#fileMenu').on('click', 'li', function () {
            var text=$(this).text()
     alert("Hello you clicked" + " " + text); // Or make($(this)); if you still want that extra function
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="fileMenu">
    <li>Refresh</li>
    <li>-</li>
    <li>Exit</li>
</ul>
<ul  id="editMenu">
    <li>Add</li>
    <li>Edit</li>
    <li>Delete</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @BhojendraNepal If you click on one of them alert will appear with the text of the li

Comment: That's what currently OP has.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Thanks for noticing it otherwise i would have got a million downvote

Answer (score 2):

You have use both the list IDs [#fileMenu, #editMenu] to achieve this. Below fiddle will help you to sort it out.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8bv9h3um/

```
$('#fileMenu, #editMenu').on('click', 'li', function () {
            alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Thank you, what is the best way to compare in jquery i.e how we use switch in c++ or c#, what is the best way to compare and perform things?